# why node-sass does'nt work in netlify when I deploy the app?

Tags: node.js, npm

*I have this error when I add node-sass to my react app, I can't deploy the app in netlify I trie to use all build cmd like CI= run build please check the result in below, the app is deployed in netlify when I remove node sass from my app and is work
help me if you can  or tell me if you need more information*

```
6:49:38 AM: Waiting for other deploys from your team to complete. Check the queue: https://app.netlify.com/teams/...
6:49:58 AM: Build ready to start
6:50:00 AM: build-image version: c5b01a919d3e16af69445c5de0cacb49efbb1a23 (focal)
6:50:00 AM: build-image tag: v4.4.0
6:50:00 AM: buildbot version: f54abf87fe81303255850790eebe8dc0b2826706
6:50:00 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
6:50:00 AM: Starting to download cache of 134.7MB
6:50:01 AM: Finished downloading cache in 904.816066ms
6:50:01 AM: Starting to extract cache
6:50:07 AM: Finished extracting cache in 5.529747047s
6:50:07 AM: Finished fetching cache in 6.47449179s
6:50:07 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
6:50:07 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
6:50:07 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
6:50:08 AM: Starting build script
6:50:08 AM: Installing dependencies
6:50:08 AM: Python version set to 2.7
6:50:08 AM: Started restoring cached node version
6:50:11 AM: Finished restoring cached node version
6:50:11 AM: v16.13.0 is already installed.
6:50:12 AM: Now using node v16.13.0 (npm v8.1.0)
6:50:12 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
6:50:12 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
6:50:12 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
6:50:13 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
6:50:14 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
6:50:14 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
6:50:14 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
6:50:14 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.1.0
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! code 1
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! path /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! command failed
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! Building: /opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass/build'
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o ../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   cc -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o ../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o.d.raw   -c
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o ../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-

6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c: In function ‘base64_encode_block’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:48:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!    48 |    result = (fragment & 0x003) << 4;
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:52:2: note: here
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!    52 |  case step_B:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:62:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!    62 |    result = (fragment & 0x00f) << 2;
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:66:2: note: here
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!    66 |  case step_C:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp: In function ‘void Sass::Functions::handle_utf8_error(const Sass::ParserState&, Sass::Backtraces)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:110:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_code_point’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   110 |       catch (utf8::invalid_code_point) {
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:114:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::not_enough_room’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   114 |       catch (utf8::not_enough_room) {
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:118:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_utf8’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   118 |       catch (utf8::invalid_utf8) {
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_encode_string(const char*)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:405:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   405 |   catch (std::exception) {
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_stringify(const JsonNode*, const char*)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:424:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   424 |   catch (std::exception) {
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! In file included from /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8.h:30,
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!                  from /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                                  ^
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                                               ^~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/node.h:821:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   821 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |                                           ^
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/node.h:855:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   855 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!   358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.167+
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
6:53:01 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2021-11-05T10_53_01_541Z-debug.log
6:53:01 AM: Error during NPM install
6:53:01 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:53:01 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:53:01 AM: Finished processing build request in 3m1.252751074s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably seems to be a version mismatch error. Downgrading the Node version to something like 12.8.0 worked for me.
To do the same in Netlify, go to `Build & Deploy -> Environment` and add the `NODE_VERSION` environment variable. Refer below attached screenshot:

[image]